# What's New ? In latest version of opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am working in Open cart Version 2.1.0.1,so can any one provide some detail of latest version of open cart.and what the difference between them.

Comment: Viewing the [changelog](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=download/download) should answer your question

Comment: https://github.com/opencart/opencart/releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=feature/blog/info&blog_id=157 OpenCart 2.3.0.2 comes with updates, bug fixes and new features, as well as 5 new payment gateways in the core:

```
Klarna
Card Connect
Divido
Pilibaba
Telecash
```